# Xt error: Can't open display despite xhost and Xauthority configured

Tags: x11

I'm attempting to display an X-capable program on another display within a local network.

I have an X server running on a host with IP 192.168.4.79, using display `:0`. I have another host (192.168.4.23) that I'd like to act as the client: that is, it should run the program and display its results to the server at 192.168.4.79:0.

On the host running the server I use xhost to add the client IP to the access control list:

```
$ xhost +192.168.4.23
```

I then extract the relevant contents of ~/.Xauthority on the server host and merge it to ~/.Xauthority on the client host.

```
$ xauth extract - $DISPLAY > xauth_extract
```

Then, copy it to over to the client host with ftp. And, on the client:

```
$ xauth merge xauth_extract
```

Alternatively, on clients supporting ssh (see note at the bottom):

```
$ xauth extract - $DISPLAY | ssh user@192.168.4.23 xauth merge -
```

However, if I run (on the client):

```
$ xterm -display 192.168.4.79:0
```

I see the error: `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 192.168.4.79:0`.

The hosts can communicate just fine: `ping -c1 192.168.4.79`. I also don't believe this is a firewall issue. First, I have my firewall setup on the host running the server to accept any connections from within the local network:

```
ipset create sjlan hash:net
ipset add sjlan 192.168.4.0/22
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set sjlan src -j ACCEPT
```

Moreover, if I temporarily disable the firewall on the server host (`systemctl stop firewall`), I get the same error.

What could I be missing here? How can I troubleshoot this?

---

I'm deliberately not using ssh for this, so please no answers for how to accomplish this with X11Forwarding. I already know how to do that and am deliberately not using it because I need this to work with a host running a 30 year old hp-ux instance (using X11R5) that does not have and cannot (with any non-trivial effort) be setup to use ssh.

Also, I'm first testing this with two modern Linux machines, both running X11R7, so the present issue is not some incompatibility between the implementation of X11 on the new machine and the one on the old machine.

I should also mention that the only thing that has worked so far is to run a server on the HP-UX machine and have the host I want to act as the server, act as the client. I was able to launch xterm from 192.168.4.79 and see its display and interact with it on the HP-UX machine. So, it appears that some setting on the new machines is blocking access. I would expect that the old machine has a much lower barrier in terms of security.

Comment: have you had a chance to run wireshark on either machine and look for the X11 packets? Maybe that offers some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X servers on most modern system have listening on IP addresses disabled by default (as it is inherently insecure), and only use the local domain sockets.

Details depend on your distro, but see `man Xserver` for the `-listen` and `-nolisten` arguments. You'll need to find out what starts the X server on your distro (display manager, systemd, ...), or you could start a second one to play around with the options (if your distro allows that).

Comment: That was it! Note that in my case, removing `-nolisten` wasn't enough. I also had to add `-listen tcp`.

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu and it did not work